# Getting Total Active Sessions, Start & End Time

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to show a chart on Power BI to show amount of active sessions by time period.

I have a set of data for car parks and need to show the amount of cars in the parking area during different times of the day.

Example of data set:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| ID | Start Time | End Time |
+====+============+==========+
|  1 | 1pm        | 2pm      |
|  2 | 1pm        | 3pm      |
|  3 | 2pm        | 3pm      |
|  4 | 3pm        | 4pm      |
|  5 | 3pm        | 5pm      |
|  6 | 3pm        | 6pm      |
|  7 | 5pm        | 7pm      |
|  8 | 5pm        | 7pm      |
|  9 | 6pm        | 7pm      |
| 10 | 6pm        | 8pm      |
+----+------------+----------+
```

I drew an example of the chart I am trying to create in Power Point based on the example data set: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiMi7.png)

Note: I've asked this question before but had gotten no response, which I then try to ask again but be more detailed in what I need (now)

Note 2: I have seen similar questions but the DAX statement has a column name that I do not have (and most of the example given was handling dates, I am using time only):

```
( 'Calendar'[Date] )
```

in

```
Measure =
VAR d =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[Start Date] <= d
                && (
                    ISBLANK ( Table1[End Date] )
                        || Table1[End Date] > d
                )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a bit of DAX and a couple of extra tables for this. 
Tables:

- Car Park Data: Needs to have VehicleID, Entry Date/Time, Leave Date/Time
- Date Table: You can quickly create one in Power Query using these [intstructions](https://www.powerquery.training/portfolio/dynamic-calendar-table/). You can probably just make a simple one that includes, Date, MonthNbr, MonthName, Year.
- Time Table: This table has one row per minute. I used [the DAX script in this blog post](https://biinsight.com/time-dimension-in-power-bi-and-ssas-tabular-model-supporting-minutes-time-bands/) to make a quick time table. (It might be more efficient to do in M, but I didn't have a script handy and it's a small table.)

Do not make any relationships between the tables.

Add the following measure:

```
Vehicles By Date And Time = 
VAR MinTime = Min('Time'[Time])
VAR MaxTime = Max('Time'[Time])
VAR MinDate = Min('Date'[Date])
Var MaxDate = Max('Date'[Date])

RETURN 
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Car Park'[Vehicle_No ]),
Filter('Car Park', TimeVALUE('Car Park'[Enter_Time]) <= MaxTime 
   && TIMEVALUE('Car Park'[Leave_Time]) >= MinTime
   && TRUNC('Car Park'[Enter_Time]) <= MaxDate 
   && TRUNC('Car Park'[Leave_Time]) >= MinDate))
```

Note: You'll have to check performance on this. It works fine for me on smaller datasets.

This measure allows you to choose a date range from the date table and a time range from the time table and uses those as the parameters to count the number of cars present over that time. I saw your comment about only using time and ignoring date, but I have added date in here to provide a better solution. Note that the dates and times are independent, so with this measure you can say "Give me all the cars that were parked between the dates of Jan 1 and April 16, only between hours of 2am and 11am."

If instead you wanted to use the date and time together rather than separately, your measure might look like this:

```
Vehicles By DateTime = 
VAR MinTime = Min('Time'[Time])
VAR MaxTime = Max('Time'[Time])
VAR MinDate = Min('Date'[Date])
Var MaxDate = Max('Date'[Date])
Var MinDateTime = MinDate + MinTime
Var MaxDateTime = MaxDate + MaxTime

RETURN 
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Car Park'[Vehicle_No ]),
Filter('Car Park', 'Car Park'[Enter_Time] <= MaxDateTime && 'Car Park'[Leave_Time] >= MinDateTime)
)
```

Here is an example to illustrate the differences:
[image]

In my data I have 6 cars. 5 of them were parked on 4/4/2018, and one was parked on 4/10/2018. If I select a date range of 1/10/2018 - 4/6/2018 and an hours range of 2am - 11 am, I can see that my Vehicles By Date and Time counts 2 cars. These two cars were parked between 2am and 11am on a date within the selected date range. Whereas if I used the other formula, I would count 5 cars because it is looking for cars that were parked between 1/10/2018 2:00:00am and 4/6/2018 11:59:00 am.

You can then add a column chart in Power BI with 60 Min Lower Band on the axis and Vehicles By Date and Time in the Value. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Have been stuck on this for so long

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create Time dimension by yourself. Since you need only "whole" hours (not minutes), you can do this by selecting "Enter Data" on home tab and then you can manually create table with hours, from 0 to 23. 
If you need Time dimension with minutes included, you can use DAX to achieve this, one of the examples can be found: [here](https://biinsight.com/time-dimension-in-power-bi-and-ssas-tabular-model-supporting-minutes-time-bands/)

After that, you just need to adjust your DAX and use column from your Time dimension.
Hope that this helps.